# PCLStorage CreateFolderAsync hanging

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am using PCL Storage library for my WP8 Application. I am trying to use intro example from their website; https://pclstorage.codeplex.com/

code:

```
IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
        IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("MySubFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("answer.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await file.WriteAllTextAsync("42");
```

CreateFolderAsync  function hangs and does not go through. I both tried on simulator and device.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look further up your call stack. You'll almost certainly find a call to `Task.Wait` or `Task<T>.Result`, thus [causing a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I describe on my blog.

To resolve, replace all `Wait` and `Result` calls with `await`. I describe this as "async all the way" in my [async best practices MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: Task<T>.Result was exactly causing problem. I was trying to return result from a async signed function. Now it works great. I will read your blog post to learn more, thanks!